# Can the index.asset.php file be used with the enqueue_block_editor_assets action?

Tags: javascript, block-editor, wp-enqueue-script

I'm developing a plugin that registers a `PluginDocumentSettingPanel` in Gutenberg. As this is not a block, I cannot use the `register_block_type` function to add its assets, so I have to employ the `enqueue_block_editor_assets` action in its place.

```
function my_enqueue_block_editor_assets() {

    $dir = dirname( __FILE__ );
    $script_asset_path = "$dir/build/index.asset.php";
    if ( ! file_exists( $script_asset_path ) ) {
        throw new Error(
            'You need to run `npm start` or `npm run build` for the block first.'
        );
    }
    $script_asset = require( $script_asset_path );

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'my-gutenberg-plugin',
        plugins_url( 'build/index.js', __FILE__ ),
        $script_asset['dependencies'],
        filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'build/index.js' )
    );

}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'my_enqueue_block_editor_assets' );
```

But, using this approach it seems that I cannot use the generated `index.asset.php` file to load the script dependencies, as I'm getting multiple `wp.editor is undefined` / `wp.coreData is undefined` / etc... errors.
If I explicitly state ALL the script dependencies using `array( 'wp-editor', 'wp-data', etc... )`, there are no errors.

Is there a way to use the `index.asset.php` file with `enqueue_block_editor_assets`? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use the index.asset.php file in the 'enqueue_block_editor_assets' action. I guess you missed to npm install the dependencies you want to use and import them in your script. That's how @wordpress/scripts generates your asset.php file. If you do not import the dependencies in your JavaScript files the dependency management of asset.php wont work.

For example:

`npm install @wordpress/api-fetch --save`

In your script:

`import apiFetch from '@wordpress/api-fetch;`

Comment: So, does this mean that, for example, I have to replace `const { useSelect } = wp.data;` with `import { useSelect } from '@wordpress/data';` ?

Comment: You have to add the import line at the top of your script, yes. You can still use wp.data in your script but you should replace that too because you can profit from code suggestions if you use VS Code or PHP Storm when you use the imported functions.

Comment: If you are importing the WordPress modules using the `import { useSelect } from '@wordpress/data';` syntax, you should not need to `npm install` anything. Using that syntax allows wp-scripts to detect which dependencies you need, and map those to the appropriate wp global properties automatically.

Put another way, using the `import` does two things:
- Populates the `dependencies` array in the asset.php so that those bundles will load first
- Automatically remaps your import statement into the correct wp.data.... or wp.editor... global reference